# Bulk edit a column and add formulas

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I have a column which contains values like

```
2015
2000
1950
```

I want to replace this column with something like

```
=YEAR(TODAY())-2015
=YEAR(TODAY())-2000
=YEAR(TODAY())-1950
```

How do I do it, if I have 1000s of rows?

I know a trick by creating new column that reference it and then hiding the original column. But I want to avoid having 2 columns if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Find and replace** to do that.

1. Open **Find and replace** (from Edit > Find and replace, or using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> shortcut)
2. In **Find** enter `^` (which - using regular expressions - matches the beginning of a line)
3. **Replace with** `=YEAR(TODAY())-` (so it will replace the beginning of the line with the beginning of the formula you want)
4. Check **Search using regular expressions**
5. In **Search** you can select ***Specific range*** and enter the range of this column (like `Sheet1!A:A` for column A)
6. Then do **Replace all**

In action:
[image]